# Hashbytes function output

Tags: sql-server, hashbytes

I have a strange situation using Hashbytes function of MSSQL 2008 R2.

Select password ,Hashbytes('SHA1', 'sa') returns
0x3608A6D1A05ABA23EA390E5F3B48203DBB7241F7.

Later I manually update my table field to this value, but 
Where Password = Hashbytes('SHA1', 'sa')
doesn't give me any result. I already used varbinary, binary, varchar, nvarchar and char data types. Please suggest what can be the problem and how I can solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174415%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), for SHA-1 you have an output size of "160 bits (20 bytes) for SHA and SHA1."

Therefore this:

```
declare @password varbinary(19); 
set @password = HASHBYTES('SHA1','sa'); 
if @password= HASHBYTES('SHA1','sa') 
    print 'yes'; 
else 
    print 'no'
```

returns `no`, since there isn't enough space to correctly store the result; but this

```
declare @password varbinary(20); 
set @password = HASHBYTES('SHA1','sa'); 
if @password= HASHBYTES('SHA1','sa') 
    print 'yes'; 
else 
    print 'no'
```

returns `yes`. If your `Password` field is `binary` or `varbinary` and has room for 20 bytes, you should be OK.

---

By the way, if you just specify `binary` or `varbinary`, without a length, you get **1** byte, which is generally not what you want.